# creating a loop for a url so that I can scrape the page for urls

Tags: python, loops, url, for-loop

thanks so much for your help. I'm trying to write a script that will scrape 589 urls and collect all of the urls on each of those 589 pages. The only thing that changes in the url is the number that follows "page="

This code isn't giving me an error message but it also isn't doing anything.

```
for i in xrange(589,1):
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.teapartynation.com/profiles/blog/list?page={}".format(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    with io.open('TPNurls.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as logfile:
       for link in soup.find_all('a', 'xj_expandable'):
            linklist=(link.get('href'))
            logfile.write(linklist + u"\n")
```

What could the problem be? I don't know where to start without an error message. Thank you in advance.

Comment: xrange(589, 1) is impossible as it means "go from 589 to 1 in increments of 1". The loop ends before it starts. Do you mean, xrange(589, 1, -1) ? Or maybe, xrange(1, 589) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
xrange(589, 1)
```

is impossible as it means "go from 589 to 1 in increments of 1". The loop ends before it starts.

You perhaps mean:

```
xrange(589, 1, -1)
```

if you prefer to go backwards from 589 to 1 (1 is excluded).

Or:

```
xrange(1, 589)
```

if you want to go forward (589 is excluded).

From `xrange` help, the syntax is:

```
xrange(start, stop[, step])
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. Also had to change the 'w' to 'a' in the file writing line.

Answer (score 0):

your

```
for i in xrange(589,1)
```

need to be

```
for i in xrange(589,1,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues but this works:

```
import urllib2
import io
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
for i in xrange(1, 589):
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.teapartynation.com/profiles/blog/list?page={}".format(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    with io.open('TPNurls.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as logfile:
       for link in soup.findAll('a', 'xj_expandable'):
            linklist=(link.get('href'))
            logfile.write(linklist + u"\n")
```

- The `xrange` arguments need to be reversed.
- You said there were 589 pages but note that `xrange(1, 589)` will only count up to 588.  If there really are 589 pages, then you need to use `xrange(1, 590)`.  This is because `xrange` stops *before* the second argument is reached.
- `soup.find_all` needs to be replaced with `soup.findAll`.